# Refactor Constant Class to Enum in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, enums

I want to refactor old code that uses a `class` of constants to `enum`, the code is already being used in a several places inside the code.(I know it's [possible in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247168/how-to-refactor-constants-to-enums-in-eclipse), but haven't found it on [IntelliJ Refactoring Dialogs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/refactoring-dialogs.html))

**Current State:**

```
public class MyConstants {
    public static String MY_CONSTANT_1 = "MY_CONSTANT_1_VALUE";
    public static String MY_CONSTANT_2 = "MY_CONSTANT_2_VALUE";
    public static String MY_CONSTANT_3 = "MY_CONSTANT_3_VALUE";
}
public class MyClass {
    //usage of constant
    if (mString.equals(MyConstants.MY_CONSTANT_1)){}
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
enum MyEnum {
        MY_CONSTANT_1("MY_CONSTANT_1_VALUE"),MY_CONSTANT_2("MY_CONSTANT_2_VALUE"),MY_CONSTANT_3("MY_CONSTANT_3_VALUE")
        private final String value;
        MyEnum(String aValue){
            value = aValue;
        }
        public String getValue(){
           return value;
        }
}
public class MyClass {
    //usage of constant
    if (mString.equals(MyConstants.MY_CONSTANT_1.getValue())){}
}
```

**Note:** I know Android [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#Overhead) recommend not to use `enum` but this is not my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with Android Studio automatically.

Comment: You have any official documentation to support you're claiming?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA documentation doesn't list all of the things you can't do with it. The list would be pretty long.

Comment: I performed extensive search on my own and found nothing.