# How do I perform a Boolean To Enum refactor in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums, refactoring, automated-refactoring

How do I perform a **Boolean To Enum** refactor in IntelliJ IDEA?

For example, convert this:

```
void changeLights(boolean isOn) {
    this.isOn = isOn;
    }

changeLights(true);
changeLights(false);
```

Into this:

```
enum LightState { ON, OFF }

void changeLights(LightState lightState) {
    this.lightState = lightState;
    }

changeLights(LightState.ON);
changeLights(LightState.OFF);
```

Comment: I have opened this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166277

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112022

Comment: For a list of manual steps you can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247168/how-to-refactor-constants-to-enums-in-eclipse/27443072#27443072

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add a method

```
@Deprecated
void changeLights(boolean isOn) {
    changeLights(isOn ? LightState.ON : LightState.OFF);
}
```

Then you can inline this method. Lastly you can "simplify" using the inspection analyse tool to simplify

```
changeLights(true ? LightState.ON : LightState.OFF); // use IDEA to simplify
```

to

```
changeLights(LightState.ON);
```

similar for false -> `changeLights(LightState.OFF);`

Comment: I was hoping there was some specialized Boolean to Enum refactoring to do just that in Intellij. So it seems it really does not exist? :(

Comment: I believe you made a small mistake there? You meant to add `void changeLights(LightState lightState) { this.lightState = lightState; }` then change the original `changeLights` method to `void changeLights(boolean isOn) { changeLights(isOn ? LightState.ON : LightState.OFF); }`, and then inline this last changed method and simplify it.